# WCF: Using multiple bindings for a single service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service (in 3.0) which is running fine with wsHttpBinding. I want  to add netTcpBinding binding also to the same service. But the challenge that I am facing is in adding behaviorConfiguration.

How should I modify the following code to enable the service for both the bindings? Please help…

```
  <service name="Lijo.Samples.WeatherService"
           behaviorConfiguration="WeatherServiceBehavior">

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/FreeServiceWorld"/>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8052/ServiceModelSamples/FreeServiceWorld"/>
        <!-- added new baseaddress for TCP-->
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="Lijo.Samples.IWeather" />

    <endpoint address=""
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              contract="Lijo.Samples.IWeather" />
    <!-- added new end point-->

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />

  </service>


</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WeatherServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Please see the following to see further details
[WCF using windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887588/wcf-using-windows-service)

Thanks

Lijo

Comment: I won't even attempt to answer this - marc_s will be along shortly to provide a high quality answer.

Comment: Hope my answer can help a little while we are waiting for marc_s :)

Comment: your config seems fine to me - what is the problem or the issue you're having?

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand what your problem or issue is - from what I'm understanding, you're unsure how to apply service behaviors?

Two things you need to consider:

- a **service behavior** can be applied to the entire `<service>` tag - so these things like metadata support etc. will affect the service per se - regardless of which endpoint you connect to
- an **endpoint behavior** can be applied to an endpoint, so that will affect only those endpoints that this behavior is applied to (and not others)

So in your case, the `WeatherServiceBehavior` will be applied to the service and thus affect all endpoints (e.g. no matter which endpoint your client connects to, it will have metadata support and debug details turned off).

So again: what exactly is your issue? Where are you "blocked" or what are you trying to do that doesn't work??

Comment: For TCP, what I understand is, we need to make httpGetEnabled="false". This is part of serviceBehaviors. And we can have only one serviceBehavior for one service. Then, how can we make the single service working for multiple bindings? Is there something like <endpointMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/> ? If yes, does endPoint behavior override service behavior? Please help. [Please be patient even if my question is foolish since I am fresher in WCF] Thanks

Comment: @Lijo: no, that httpGetEnabled setting is no a problem at all - just go for it! It wouldn't make sense to have this enabled if you had only netTcp endpoints - but it's not bothering netTcp at all. This setting just simply enables you to grab the service metadata using HTTP (by adding ?wsdl to your service URL) - it doesn't have any effect whatsoever on your netTcp endpoints.....

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the address of the net tcp endpoint, at the endpoint level, not as a base address.

Also test if first with just nettcp binding to make sure that that works, before you try to configure for both.